# Seeking intuition on hat-check probability depending on parity of $n$

Tags: probability

In (one version of) the hat-check problem, https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hat-Check_Problem the question is to find the probability that for $n$ hat-checkers, nobody gets their own hat. If this is called $p_n,$ the solution is to obtain the $n$th partial sum of the series for $1/e.$

So we have, for $n=1,2,3,\cdots,$ that
$$p_n=\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}.$$

For odd $n,$ the likelihood increases as $n$ does. This seems peculiar (to me) in that for more people checking their hats, it would become *more* likely that at least one person got their own hat, and so less likely that nobody did.

For even $n$ as $n$ goes up the likelihood $p_n$ decreases as expected by the vague (incorrect) intuition proposed above.

I'm looking for some reasonable intuitive reason why one would expect this even/odd $n$ behavior for this problem. Also from the answer, for any $m,n$ where $m$ even and $n$ odd, $p_m>p_n,$ which puzzles my intuition more.

Any intuitions (not proofs, which can be done and are known anyway) appreciated.